# Url.Action in controller generates port twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url.action

I am using below piece of code to generate a fully qualified `url` and pass it back as `json` for redirection.

```
returnUrl = Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", 
                       new RouteValueDictionary(new { type= returnUrl }), 
                       HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, 
                       HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority);
```

`returnUrl` will initially have a value either `type1` or `type2` which is why I have given type as `returnUrl` and then replacing its value with a generated `url`, but it generates

```
http://localhost:49518:49518/Controller/ActionName?type=type1
                     //^^^^^ Extra port added
```

and appends port number `49518` twice. What could be the possible solution to this? Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority` with  `HttpContext.Request.Url.Host`.

Because :

- `HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority` returns the Domain Name System (DNS) host name or IP address and **the port number** for a server.
- `HttpContext.Request.Url.Host` returns the DNS host name or IP address of the server.

In your code you are using an overload of `Url.Action` that accept the host name instead of the authority which contains the port.

With this fix your port will be automatically added and there will be not port duplication.

Comment: Will this work as expected in production? I hope it should.. :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound - It didn't work for me, on server, it is still returning port number for me.

Comment: @WriteTheCode lol if it didn’t work for you just create your own question on StackOverflow and put it what is not working. For This one it is working for the OP. Thanks and have a good day.