# Url.Action in controller generates port twice on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url.action

I referred [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586598/url-action-in-controller-generates-port-twice) - but it didn't work.

I am using below piece of code to generate a fully qualified url and pass it to script and use this url there to redirect.

```
 @section Scripts
 {
    @Html.Script(@<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let targetUrl = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("action", "controller",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { Area = "Schemes" }),
            Request.Url.Scheme,
            Request.Url.Host))';

        let script = new ListScript(targetUrl);
        script.initialize();           
    });
    </script>)
```

}

http://servername:9565/Controller/ActionName
                     //^^^^^ Extra port added
and appends port number 9565 twice. What could be the possible solution to this? Why this is happening?

Comment: The port is being added after the ActionName? or after the other port.

Comment: after another port - http://servername:9565/Controller/ActionName - The (fictional) servername already has a port defined.

Comment: Are you generating the URL in the view or Controller? It looks like in the view.

Comment: In the script section of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in Controller.

```
var url = Url.Action("action", "controller", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Area = "Schemes" }), HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
```

In View.

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Area = "Schemes" }), Context.Request.Scheme, Context.Request.Host.ToString())
```

Also on a side note, do you need to wrap the Url.Action in Html.Raw, you just need the string value URL right?

Comment: We were doing it like this only, it didn't work, so we tried with HttpContext.Request.Host, but that too didn't work.

Comment: What is the values of these two on their own?

HttpContext.Request.Scheme &
HttpContext.Request.Host

Comment: It too didn't work. Sorry. I think I'll have to do it via regex in script.

Comment: Are both ports showing same? Do you have both HTTP and HTTPS enabled?

Comment: Yes both ports are same, with HTTPS enabled.

Comment: Try and disable HTTPS and see if it generates both port still.

Comment: Well, I don't have access to the server so can't do that rn. But I handled it differently, via javascript. Removed port manually.